# check the json response is array or int or string for a key?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having the json response in which "products" key sometime having the int value and some cases it had an array?
How to check whether it is having array or Int?

```
"products": 25
```

or

```
"products": [77,80,81,86]
```

I am using this

```
self.productsCount = mResp["products"] as! [Int]
```

but it is crashed every time when it is not having array.

Now i am not getting how to check this because i have the different option for Int and Array?

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: you can use Any then check Any is Integer or array

Comment: That is a bad API design, I'd see if you can fix the API problem rather than making your app work around it.

Comment: yes i know this is bad, but there might be some way to solve this problem? @Scriptable

Comment: Also don't force unwrap it, if you use if let/guard let you can distinguish too.

Comment: there is... but why solve a problem by working around it... fix the problem instead

Comment: `if let array = mResp["products"] as? [Int] {// this is an array}` by same way you can check others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to fall back to `Any` here. Even problematic JSON like this can be handled with `Codable`. You just need to keep trying the different types until one works.

```
struct Thing: Decodable {
    let products: [Int]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // First pull out the "products" key
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        do {
            // Then try to decode the value as an array
            products = try container.decode([Int].self, forKey: .products)
        } catch {
            // If that didn't work, try to decode it as a single value
            products = [try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .products)]
        }
    }
}


let singleJSON = Data("""
{ "products": 25 }
""".utf8)

let listJSON = Data("""
{ "products": [77,80,81,86] }
""".utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

try! decoder.decode(Thing.self, from: singleJSON).products   // [25]
try! decoder.decode(Thing.self, from: listJSON).products     // [77, 80, 81, 86]
```

Comment: Would this line work `products = [try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .products)]` with products been defined as an array of ints (`[Int]`)? I didn't think it would, **EDIT**: just copied code into playground and can confirm that it **does work**

Comment: @Scriptable I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you have an example JSON that this doesn't parse? (The above results are right out of a playground).  The result of `[ ...expression that returns Int...]` is `[Int]`, so this type checks fine.

Comment: just updated my comment. I didnt think it would take an Int value (non array) and assign it to the products int array. but it did. Good to know, thanks

Comment: It definitely doesn't do that. The brackets in the expression are required to create an Array.  You can't say `products = 1` but you can write `products = [1]` (`1` being an expression that returns an Int)

Comment: `{ "products": 25 }` is not an array. products is defined as `let products: [Int]` which is why i thought `try! decoder.decode(Thing.self, from: singleJSON).products` would not work. but it does. That is what caused my confusion, as it is taking a JSON value of 25 and assigning it into products which is an array. doesn't matter now anyway, it works, i just wanted to understand how thats all. Good answer

Comment: Ahhh, i see the brackets you refer to now!, completely missed those. thanks

Answer (score 4):

It crashes because you force unwrap as an Integer Array, even though you just have an integer. The solution is to check for both:

```
self.productsCount = mResp["products"] as? [Int] ?? mResp["products"] as? Int
```

**Other Solution**

```
if let proCount = mResp["products"] as? [Int] { 
  self.productsCount = proCount
} else {
  self.productsCount = mResp["products"] as? Int
}
```

Comment: when i am using this then Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Int]?' and 'Int?' this error occurs

Answer (score 3):

This is temporary solution as you want. Check for possible type with "Any" type.

```
    var anyType : Any!
    anyType = "123"
    anyType = ["Test","Test1"]
    anyType = 1
    if anyType is Array {
        print("is Array")
    }else if anyType is String {
        print("is String")
    }else if anyType is Int {
        print("is Int")
    }
```

Comment: Dont use NSArray in Swift

Answer (score 2):

let's assume your json name is `jsonData`

Check for `Int` and `Array Int`:

```
if let intVal = jsonData["products"] as? Int {
    print("Products is a Integer: ", intVal)

} else if let jsonArr = jsonData["products"] as? [Int] {

    var intVals = [Int]()
    for json in jsonArr {
        intVals.append(json)
    }
    print("Json is array of Int: ", intVals)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let dict = [77,80,81,86]//Pass your parameter or parsed json value
 if dict is Array<Any> {
    print("Yes, it's an Array")
}
else{
      print("NO, it's not an Array")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic solution would be like this,

```
let products = mResp["products"] as? Any
if let item = products as? [Int] {
    print("array", item)
} else if let item = products as? Int {
    print("Integer", item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Generics` for obtaining a better solution and provide the type at the time of decoding this model.

```
struct Product<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let products: T?
}
```

And you can use it with nested `try catch`:

```
do {
    let product = try JSONDecoder().decode(Product<Int>.self, from: data)
    print(product)
} catch {
    do {
        let product = try JSONDecoder().decode(Product<[Int]>.self, from: data)
        print(product)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Note: This solution assumes there is not more than a few different type-varying properties in the codable struct. If there are multiple type-varying properties I'd recommend use a custom `init(decoder:)` as provided in the accepted answer which would be much better design instead of having a `try-catch` tree.